# Image positioning in CSS powered menu

Tags: html, css

So, I have this:

```
 .line {
    width:100%;
    height:4px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url("http://goolag.pw/line2.png");
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

It's pretty simple what's supposed to do, and it does the job. The problem is, if I try to put it in my menu (css and html are too long, here's the link: http://goolag.pw/temptest.html) it either completely destroys the menu itself, or it just doesn't show up, or it isn't on the bottom.. As you can see, the line is working propebly outside of the menu, but inside of it, it doesn't show up on the bottom. I tried putting it everywhere in the menu, am I doing something wrong? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The link is not opening. Can you jsfiddle it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xj4Zn/ Here you go, may not be the same though.

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  I see the line just fine right underneath Contact.  where in the menu should it be?

Comment: On the bottom, just as the CSS .line shows. Basically right where it's when you don't have the menu up.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick look... You need to set an over-all wrapper to (or somethingt to) relative that will encompass all content. You're positioning absolutely to the bottom which means once the menu opens up, that content is determining the height of the parent so the line goes to the bottom, but it's going to the bottom of the menu.

Either set position:relative on a containing element or check any scripts or injected css to make sure that when the menu rolls into place position:relative isn't being set on the div containing the menu.

Comment: Well.. I am not that skilled in HTML, and I didn't understand half of the stuff you said..

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="goolag_games.html">Goolag Games</a></li>
           <li><a href="wai.html">Who am I?</a></li>
           <li><a href="wita.html">What is this about?</a></li> 
           <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.line {
    width:100%;
    height:4px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url("http://goolag.pw/line2.png");
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I placed "line" inside of "nav" and changed the z-index of it to 1000. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, it does the job, but is there a way for it to show up only in the menu?